# How can a garbage collector find out about object references done from the stack?

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, go

In languages with automatic garbage collection like Haskell or Go, how can the garbage collector find out which values stored on the stack are pointers to memory and which are just numbers? If the garbage collector just scans the stack and assumes all addresses to be references to objects, a lot of objects might get incorrectly marked as reachable.

Obviously, one could add a value to the top of each stack frame that described how many of the next values are pointers, but wouldn't that cost a lot of performance?

How is it done in reality?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There exist GCs that assume that every bit pattern that is the address of something the GC is managing *is* in fact a pointer (and so don't release the something). This can actually work pretty well, because calls pointers are usually bigger than small common integers, and usually have to be aligned. But yes, this can cause collection of some objects to be delayed. The Boehm collector for C works this way, because it's library-based and so don't get any specific help from the compiler.

There are also GCs that are more tightly coupled to the language they're used in, and actually know the structure of the objects in memory. I've never read up specifically in stack frame handling, but you could record information to help the GC if the compiler and GC are designed to work together. One trick would be putting all the pointer references together and using one word per stack frame to record how many there are, which is not such a huge overhead. If you can work out what function corresponds to each stack frame without adding a word saying so, then you could have a per-function "stack frame layout map" compiled in. Another option would be to use tagged words, where you set the low order bit of words that are not pointers to 1, which (due to address alignment) is never needed for pointers, so you can tell them apart. That means you have to shift unboxed values in order to use them though.

Comment: +1 for discussing the Boehm collector, which uses a frankly brilliant approach.

Answer (score 20):

Some collectors assume everything on the stack is a potential pointer (like Boehm GC).  This turns out to be not as bad as one might expect, but is clearly suboptimal.  More often in managed languages, some extra tagging information is left with the stack to help the collector figure out where the pointers are.

Remember that in most compiled languages, the layout of a stack frame is the same every time you enter a function, therefore it is not that hard to ensure that you tag your data in the right way.

The "bitmap" approach is one way of doing this.  Each bit of the bitmap corresponds to one word on the stack.  If the bit is a 1 then the location on the stack is a pointer, and if it is a 0 then the location is just a number from the point of view of the collector (or something along those lines).  The exceptionally well written GHC runtime and calling conventions use a one word layout for most functions, such that a few bits communicate the size of the stack frame, with the rest serving as the bitmap.  Larger stack frames need a multi word structure, but the idea is the same.

The point is that the overhead is low, since the layout information is computed at compile time, and then included in the stack every time a function is called.

An even simpler approach is "pointer first", where all the pointers are located at the beginning of the stack.  You only need to include a length prior to the pointers, or a special "end" word after them, to tell which words are pointers given this layout.

Interestingly, trying to get this management information on to the stack produces a host of problem related to interop with C.  For example, it is sub optimal to compile high level languages to C, since even though C is portable, it is hard to carry this kind of information.  Optimizing compilers designed for C like languages (GCC,LLVM) may restructure the stack frame, producing problems, so the GHC LLVM backend uses its own "stack" rather than the LLVM stack which costs it some optimizations.  Similarly, the boundary between C code, and "managed" code needs to be constructed carefully to keep from confusing the GC.

For this reason, when you create a new thread on the JVM you actually create two stacks (one for Java, one for C).

Comment: For some platforms (e.g. IA-64, x86-64) and operating systems (such as Linux), you can use libunwind (http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/) to unwind the stack and have access to the C stack frames. This takes out some of the complexity dealing with the C stack (but aggressive compiler optimizations may still cause problems).

Comment: Why is Haskell using the bitmap-approach? Wouldn't it be better to use the pointers-first approach?

Comment: It seems that LLVM actually does have [support for garbage collection](http://goo.gl/AzLsr).

Comment: @FUZxxl, from the GHC Commentary: "Unlike heap objects which mainly have "pointers first" layout, in a stack frame the pointers and non-pointers are intermingled. This is so that we can support "stack stubbing" whereby a live variable stored on the stack can be later marked as dead simply by pushing a new stack frame that identifies that slot as containing a non-pointer, so the GC will not follow it."

Answer (score 16):

The Haskell stack uses a single word of memory in each stack frame describing (with a bitmap) which of the values in that stack frame are pointers and which are not.  For details, see the ["Layout of the stack"](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/Stack) article and the ["Bitmap layout"](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects?redirectedfrom=Commentary/Rts/HeapObjects#Bitmaplayout) article from the GHC Commentary.

To be fair, a single word of memory really isn't much cost, all things considered.  You can think of it as just adding a single variable to each method; that's not all that bad.

Comment: Small correction - the single word is in the stack frame *info table*, not the stack frame itself. Or put another way: The stack frame contains just the return pointer, which can be followed to find both the code as well as the info table encoding the stack layout. Meaning no actual space overhead on the stack.

Comment: Hmmmkay.  I was misled by the paragraph: "Unlike heap objects which mainly have "pointers first" layout, in a stack frame the pointers and non-pointers are intermingled...Stack frames therefore have bitmap layout."  So if I understand you correctly, having bitmap layout means there's a bitmap somewhere -- but not on the stack itself -- with this information.  I suppose that calls to the same method would always have the same stack frame layout, so the bitmap gets shared, in the info table?

Comment: Note we aren't talking about calls here, but return closures. But yes, both *statically* know the stack layout of their frame, as, after all, the data is on the stack for the sole purpose of them using it.

Answer (score 8):

It's important to realize that GHC maintains its own stack and does not use the C stack (other than for FFI calls).  There's no portable way to access all of the contents of the C stack (for instance, in a SPARC some of it is hidden away in register windows), so GHC maintains a stack where it has full control.  Once you maintain your own stack you can pick any scheme to distinguish pointers from non-pointers on the stack (like a using a bitmap).